# Inline action menu embedded in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-menu

I'm trying to create an inline menu as part of a layout. In other words, I want a "three dots" menu overflow icon (such as the one in the below example), placed on its own somewhere in my layout, and upon clicking it a standard menu should pop up.

[image]

At first I tried embedding a `Toolbar` from the support library in my layout, and while it does result in the menu overflow icon being shown, it's not ideal for my situation; a toolbar is a wide component intended to include a title, sub-title, icon etc. I only need the menu icon and behavior. Also, I have failed to style the toolbar to my liking, including getting rid of the quite large margin around the menu overflow icon. It would make more sense to use a simpler component for just the menu then trying to make a `Toolbar` fit into my layout.

I know that `Toolbar` internally uses an `ActionMenuView` to implement the menu, so I then tried including an `ActionMenuView` in my layout, and attach a menu to it from code:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

...

ActionMenuView amv = (ActionMenuView)findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.some_menu, amv.getMenu());
amv.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...)
```

This however only results in an invisible view. When using a `Toolbar` and writing the equivalent code to attach a menu to it, the menu overflow icon is automatically shown and can be clicked, but when using a stand-alone `ActionMenuView` I just cannot get it to work.

I even tried to hard-code the width and height to 50dp, and while the view is visible in Android Studio's layout preview window, it's not visible on device (hierarchy viewer shows its height to be zero).

Now, of course I guess I can create an `ImageButton` with the desired icon and manually implement a menu behavior on it, but surely there must be a simple way to get the existing component working?

Comment: Did you find any solution?